I want to make refresh token API call every 60 minutes
I currently have a refresh token API call every 60 minutes,
Here is my condition:
 **const expires_in = 3600 //This is 3600s comes from auth api 
if (refreshToken && expires_in * 1000 > Date.now() + 3600000) {
// RefreshToken Function
else {
        console.log("accessToken not expired yet");
    }**

This condition is not working properly. This condition calls RefreshToken Function on every reload but I want to call this after every 60 minutes.
Accurate my condition which is to call after every 60 minutes.

what http package are you using? Axios ors fetch?

You would also need to know the date time when the token was issued for this to work.

At this time I am using fetch call

First store this date whenever you got the new access token.
// This snippet adds 3600 seconds to the current date
const accessTokenTime = new Date();
accessTokenTime.setSeconds(accessTokenTime.getSeconds() + expires_in);

After that you can compare the two dates, If the accessTokenTime less than the current time, means the 60 minutes is completed for the acccessToken.
if (refreshToken && (accessTokenTime < Date.now()) {
    // RefreshToken Function
} else {
   console.log("accessToken not expired yet");
}


Not working yet I want to call RefreshToken API when access token is expire and my access token expire time is one hour(60 minutes).

Did you add the first snippet, while you got the accessToken at the beginning?
Can you give the log value of accessTokenTime Date.now()?

Here is the object which I get after login successfully.
{
"access_token": "pA6StAHCIW2UdsrkghrMJjpOdHsjkfwJeyRvXviSY",
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "channels channel_contacts files channel_messages logs",
"refresh_token": "78KOriUIAofHGs2LO3bfdHc2LHsdjghjkgwexCis"
}
Kindly suggest me how can I manage my refresh token condition.

Just add the first snippet after login, where you get this object : { "access_token": "pA6StAHCIW2UdsrkghrMJjpOdHsjkfwJeyRvXviSY", "expires_in": 3600, "token_type": "Bearer", "scope": "channels channel_contacts files channel_messages logs", "refresh_token": "78KOriUIAofHGs2LO3bfdHc2LHsdjghjkgwexCis" }
And consume the accessTokenTime, where you need the check the access token is expired or not.

Can you not just use a sleep function, or something like that ?

Kindly explain exactly what you want say.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

expires_in * 1000 = 3600000 ,
Date.now() + 3600000 = 1720672843350 ,
So the condition can never be true.
Also your could should look like:
    const expires_in = 3600 //This is 3600s comes from auth api 
     if ((refreshToken) && (expires_in * 1000 > Date.now() + 3600000)) {
   // RefreshToken Function

     }else {

    console.log("accessToken not expired yet");
  }

In this case you are expecting both conditions to be true to execute the function.
But here as I told you :
The first condition can never be greater than the second one, which means you will never be able to execute the function according to your condition.
Maybe you wanted to say:
    const expires_in = 3600 //This is 3600s comes from auth api 
 if ((refreshToken) && (expires_in * 1000 + Date.now() > Date.now() + 3600000)) 
{
  // RefreshToken Function

 }else {

console.log("accessToken not expired yet");

}
My advice is to correct the math first and figure out what exactly should the condition be like.

Your condition is show always false.
